# Setting PIdgin up for Lync2013

Tags: pidgin, microsoft-lync, pidgin-sipe

I having difficulty setting up pidgin to work with my company's microsoft 365's communicator lync 2013 (not 2010) account.

I either receive a message stating authentication failed, or `Incompatible authentication scheme chosen: NTLM` depending upon the user agent values used from [this wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/sipe/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/)

It appears that both the user agent values that start with UCCAPI provide authentication failed error, which I'm guessing is "closer" to the solution.

I have triple checked that the password is correct.

Below are some images of my settings (I have changed the company name to "company" for annonymity.

[image]
[image]

I am running pidgin with a script in order to fix a write error issue:

```
export NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0
pidgin -d
```

I am also using the latest version of SIPE (1.10.1) by using this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~aavelar/+archive/ppa

What settings do I need to change/add to get it to work?

Comment: Did you try using the full user agent string? `UCCAPI/15.0.4420.1017 OC/15.0.4420.1017 (Microsoft Lync)`

Comment: My company switched over to use Office 365 and I needed to adjust some settings, I found the information here to be helpful: http://www.vincentpassaro.com/2013/02/01/configuring-pidgin-instant-messenger-for-office-365-lync/

Comment: Did you ever get your contact names to display in Pidgin running on Windows ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Paulreg Names only appear for me when I have manually added them to lync. It's a major pain and would love a solution to that.

Comment: The advice given on this page used to work great, but stopped working during the summer. I now get "Failed to authenticate to server" or "Incompatible authentication scheme chosen" depending on the settings I chose, but nothing works. Does anyone have any insight? I'd offer a bounty, but I don't have enough rep :-(

Comment: @mason81 : the link to vincentpassaro.com is dead ...

Comment: Note: As of Ubuntu 16.04/xenial, pidgin-sipe is in `universe`. The latest version there is newer than the latest in the PPA mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to get this working on ubuntu 13.04 (question asked on ubuntu 12.04). Here are a few pointers:

Use the full user agent string as @mason81 pointed out:

```
UCCAPI/15.0.4420.1017 OC/15.0.4420.1017 (Microsoft Lync)
```

I did **not** need to use a startup script to solve any write errors. e.g.

```
export NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0
pidgin -d
```

That [linked repo](https://launchpad.net/~aavelar/+archive/ppa) was pointless on this distro, don't use it. It appears that on Ubuntu 13.04 you will install pidgin-sipe 1.13.3-1 by default which is an even more up-to-date version.

It appears that the pidgin/sipe setup I have installed here has a third authentication type for TLS as seen in this picture which is what I needed.
[image]

---

For reference, here are my connection settings that are working:
[image]
[image]

The other tabs are the defaults

---

**Update**

To get this working in ubuntu 14.04, do exactly the same, but untick the single sign on!

Comment: Thanks for the update for 14.04 -- I finally got around to upgrading and then couldn't connect to lync and it was driving me crazy!

Comment: This configuration works on the Windows version of the Pidgin client too.  I didn't tick single sign-on, not sure if it makes any difference.  Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed this also works on 16.04. (With single sign-on unchecked.)

Answer (score 5):

I manged to get this working on Ubuntu 12.04 with the pidgin (2.10.3) and  pidgin-sipe (1.11.2-1ubuntu1) installed from the default precise/universe repo. We are using Lync2013 also.

I did use an environment variable to run pidgin. Without this pidgin would fail every time with a 'Read failed'. This was configured in `/home/myuser/.profile` by appending:

```
export NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0
```

Check [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=770682) for more information about why this variable is needed for sipe.

The sipe settings were as follows

'Basic' tab:

- Username: my email as used within the company (e.g
  john.smith@company.co.uk)
- Login: company logon domain\username (e.g
  COMPANY\john.smith)

***Advanced*** tab:

- Connections type: Auto
- User Agent: UCCAPI/15.0.4420.1017
  OC/15.0.4420.1017 (Microsoft Lync)
- Use Single Sign-on: [ticked]

All other fields in ***Advanced*** were blank. I had no proxy configured.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is currently working for me. I have an Office365 account.

BASIC TAB

Username: username@company.com

Login: username@company.com

Password: *****

[CHECK]Remember password

Local alias: My Name

ADVANCED TAB

Server[:Port]: BLANK

Connection type: SSL/TLS

User Agent: UCCAPI/15.0.4481.1000 OC/15.0.4481.1000 (Microsoft Lync)

Authentication scheme: TLS-DSK

[UNCHECK]Use Single Sign-On

The rest is blank

Answer (score 2):

Took a while to sort out, but this article did help quite a bit. Things to know:

1. User agent is different depending on version of Lync your company has running and it's patch level. I found my agent by finding someone on MS Lync (not linux) and looking in a uccapilog file (it's under the Lync\Tracing directory) searching for UCCAPI.
2. I at least had to find the server, and had to use the direct IP instead of DNS, found that info in the same file as above.
3. The authentication scheme is dependent on your company's choices when they setup Lync, mine was NTLM.
4. I did not use Single-Sign-on as my workstation login is not my domain login.

Comment: To which “article” are you referring?

Comment: @DavidFoerster it's definitely unclear but he may be referring to this Q & A?

Answer (score 1):

If you have you got MultiFactorAuthentication enabled you will need to give "app password" in the basic tab and email login and email password in the advanced tab.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: I first got Pidgin/SIPE working on Ubuntu following Programster's instructions. I then tried on Windows and it failed with an error message

```
Web ticket request to https://webpoolams0e08.infra.lync.com:443/CertProv/CertProvisioningService.svc failed
```

Unticking SSO, again according to Programster's, instructions solved that. Only problem now is that no names are visible for my Lync contacts. If I mouse over they a "tool tip" with the name appear but the name remain invisible when the mouse is not there.