# import Certificate in Pdgin for Microsoft Lync 2013

Tags: pidgin, certificates, microsoft-lync

I follow [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360205/setting-pidgin-up-for-lync2013) to configure PIdgin for MS Lync 2013 .

I get this message :

> Web ticket request to
>   https://rproxy.mycompany.com:443/CertProv/CertProvisioningService.svc
>   failed

[image]

Known that settings has been configured as following: 
 [image]

And No proxy: 
[image]

i received this certificate from MS sysadmin .

[image]
And i don't know if it is useful in Ubuntu  . If so , How can i import it?

And Why **rproxy** appeared in message error even there is no proxy in my settings .

I mean :

> https://rproxy.mycompany.com:443/CertProv/CertProvisioningService.svc

**UPDATE :**

I found where can i import certificate :

[image]

However , i get new error message:

> SSL Connection Failed

Known that Authentication Scheme is: **Kerberos** , not TLS-DSK

Answer (score 0):

Just found that posting here and decided to leave some answers as no input was given:

1. The proxy in the name isn't a proxy on your PC, it is a reverse proxy which seemed to be used in the lync implementation on your side
2. Pidgin on Lync 2013 works fine with TLS-DSK enabled
3. Make sure that you use the correct user agent, Lync has a policy which can block clients which aren't in a list configured by the admin

Answer (score 0):

Just use <kbd>Edit your account</kbd>:

```
username : "your EmailId"
Login    : "Domain/UserId"
```